# How to filter and arrange object array based on attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the JSON array of items:

```
var items = [
  {
    Id: "c1",
    config:{
      url:"/c1",
      content: "c1 content",
      parentId: "p1",
      parentUrl: "/p1",
      parentContent: "p1 content",
    }
  },
    {
    Id: "c2",
    config:{
      url:"/c2",
      content: "c2 content",
      parentId: "p1",
      parentUrl: "/p1",
      parentContent: "p1 content",
    }
  },
      {
    Id: "c3",
    config:{
      url:"/c3",
      content: "c3 content"
    }
  },
  ]
```

The result should be something like this:

```
var items = [
  {
    Id: "p1",
    config:{
      url:"/p1",
      content: "p1 content"
    },children:[
      {
        Id: "c1",
        config:{
          url:"/c1",
          content: "c1 content"
          }
      },{
        Id: "c2",
        config:{
          url:"/c2",
          content: "c2 content"
          }
      },
       ]
  },
  {
    Id: "c3",
    config:{
      url:"/c3",
      content: "c3 content"
    }
  },
  ]
```

If an object has parent properties they should be wrapped under parent's children prop. I am finding it very difficult to convert this. Can anyone help me out in this? Thank you.

Comment: Why not provide the data in the format you require?

Comment: @iblamefish The exact format that I am having has a lot of properties and many nested objects so I just put it in a simple example.

Comment: post the code you have tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is NOT tested, but hope it helps:

```
var new_items = [];

for(i in items) {
  var id = items[i].config.parentId;
  if(id) {
    if(!(parent = get_parent(id))) { // If the new list does not contain the parent...
      parent = {Id: id, config: {
        url: items[i].config.parentUrl,
        content: items[i].config.parentContent,
        //... The parent attributes
      }, children: []};
    }
    parent.children.push({/* The child object attributes*/});

  }
}

function get_parent(id) {
  for(ni in new_itmes) {
    if(new_items[ni].Id == id) return new_items[ni];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The array to process (note that I added an item for p1):

```
var items = [{
    Id: "p1",
    config:{}
  },{
    Id: "c1",
    config:{
      url:"/c1",
      content: "c1 content",
      parentId: "p1",
      parentUrl: "/p1",
      parentContent: "p1 content",
    }
  },{
    Id: "c2",
    config:{
      url:"/c2",
      content: "c2 content",
      parentId: "p1",
      parentUrl: "/p1",
      parentContent: "p1 content",
    }
  },{
    Id: "c3",
    config:{
      url:"/c3",
      content: "c3 content"
    }
  },
];
```

Process the array:

```
orphans = [];
parents = {};
items.forEach(function(item){
    parents[item.Id]=item;
});
items.forEach(function(item){
  var parent = parents[item.config.parentId];
  if (parent){
    parent.children = parent.children || [];
    parent.children.push(item);
  }else{
    orphans.push(item);
  }
});
console.log('Processed array:', orphans);
```